# Structure of a sentence in Bernhard Schlink's "Der Vorleser"

Tags: sentence-structure, literature

I'm reading Bernhard Schlink's novel "Der Vorleser" and got stuck trying to understand this sentence in the beginning of the second chapter:

> Kein Stuck, keine Spiegel, kein Läufer. **Was das Treppenhaus
>   ursprünglich an bescheidener, der Prächtigkeit der Fassade nicht
>   vergleichbarer Schönheit besessen haben mochte, war längst vergangen.**

I understand "Was das Treppenhaus ursprünglich ... besessen haben mochte, war längst vergangen" as "Whatever `blank` the staircase may originally have possessed had long been gone".

What I don't understand is:

1. What's the function of the preposition "an" as in "an bescheidener..."?
2. What noun is "bescheidener" referring to?
3. "der Prächtigkeit der Fassade nicht vergleichbarer Schönheit". I don't understand the structure here at all. I'm not sure of the cases and overall meaning of this bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The part you are missing is *"an bescheidener, der Prächtigkeit der Fassade nicht vergleichbarer Schönheit"*.
We have an adjective and an adjectival phrase here:
*Die Schönheit des Treppenhauses war*:

- *bescheiden* (modest)
- *der Prächtigkeit der Fassade nicht vergleichbar*
  = *nicht vergleichbar mit der Prächtigkeit der Fassade*
  (not comparable with the splendor of the facade)

*Der Prächtichkeit* is dative, *der Fassade* is genitive

The usage of "an" is idiomatic here

> Das Treppenhaus besitzt bescheidene Schönheit ->
>   Was das Treppenhaus an bescheidener Schönheit besitzt ...

Comment: Oh, now I see. What threw me off here was that in English one would use a preposition to link the adjective "comparable" to "beauty", whereas in German one simply uses the dative case. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 2):

That's quite a sentence you found there!

First of, *was an* (plus dative). It's a construction that can sometimes be paraphrased by *was für*, sometimes by *welche*.

> Weißt du, **was** der Anbieter **an Gebühren** verlangt?
>   Weißt du, **was für Gebühren** der Anbieter verlangt? (*what kind of fees*)
>   Weißt du, **welche Gebühren** der Anbieter verlangt? (*which fees*)

(Neither paraphrase is perfect. To me, the English phrases *as far as fees are concerned* or *in terms of fees* match the meaning of *an Gebühren* in the above example pretty closely.)

In the above examples, *was* is the object of the verb; *was* is modified by the prepositional phrase *an Gebühren*, and that's just the way it is in your example.

> **Was** das Treppenhaus **an ...** besessen haben mochte

Let's look inside the prepositional phrase and build it up piece by piece.

> an Schön**heit** (feminine head noun)
>   an bescheiden**er**, vergleichbar**er** Schönheit (two adjectives depending on the head noun)

The adjective *vergleichbar* is extended. Compare the following:

> Ich kenne keinen Künstler, der **(mit) ihm vergleichbar** wäre. (sentential structure)
>   Ich kennen keinen **(mit) ihm vergleichbaren** Künstler. (adjectival phrase)
>
> an Schönheit, die **(mit) der Prächtigkeit der Fassade nicht vergleichbar** war
>   an **(mit) der Prächtigkeit der Fassade nicht vergleichbarer** Schönheit

The sentence is quite easily translated if the the adjectival phrase headed by *vergleichbar* is moved into a parenthetical phrase:

> What the staircase may originally have possessed in terms of modest beauty, a beauty that was not comparable to the splendor of the façade, was long gone.

Answer (score 1):

> Was das Treppenhaus ursprünglich besessen haben mochte, war längst vergangen.
>
> Was das Treppenhaus ursprünglich **an bescheidener Schönheit** besessen haben mochte, war längst vergangen.
>
> Was das Treppenhaus ursprünglich **an nicht vergleichbarer Schönheit** besessen haben mochte, war längst vergangen.
>
> Was das Treppenhaus ursprünglich **an der Prächtigkeit der Fassade nicht vergleichbarer Schönheit** besessen haben mochte, war längst vergangen.

It's a list of two adverbials lead by *an*. The second adverbial has additional genitive supplements. Such genitive supplements are common in German. In English you have to use *of*, which leads to a very clumsy literal translation:

*Whatever the staircase may originally have possessed of the not comparable beauty of the pomp of the front had long been gone.*

Please note the correct placement of *not compareable* is hard to find. I think I found the best solution, though some attachment of *nicht vergleichbar* to *Fassade* got lost in translation. This is somewhat related to genitive supplements, it seems. They are more tightly bound to an item than prepositional phrases.

---

Such *an* adverbials often talk about a type of supplies:

> Die Vorräte an Bier gehen zur Neige.
>
> Sie besitzen einiges an Vermögen, sind aber arm an Geist.

Comment: Try *the pomp of the front's incomparable beauty*.

Comment: That's a Germanism, isn't it?

Comment: @vectory The original doesn't say the beauty of the facade is incomparable, it only says the beauty of the stairway doesn't compare to it

Comment: Indeed, I see now, but that's missing in this translation anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

The construction *etwas an ... haben* is peculiar indeed. Taken out of context, it would remind of *Kleidung anhaben* (*to wear clothes*), and the preposition also appears in *jemandem etwas anhaben* (*to afflict someone with something*) and conversely *das kann mir nichts anhaben* (loosely *that has nothing on me, does nothing bad to me*).

However, the expression could also be found with the preposition *von*, i.e. *etwas von Schönheit haben* or more usually *etwas von jemandem* [or *etwas anderem*] *haben* (*to have an apparence reminiscent of someone* [or *something else*], *as if taken from*; compare *reminding on*).

We say *was hast du an Sorten zur Auswahl*; more usually *was für Sorten*, I'd say. So we can deduce that *an* works in it's usual function denoting direction, *towards, for*, thus abstractly

> **in favor of**

Prepositions are idiomatic and don't always translate well. A historical derivation would likely complicate the exposition.

Comment: I am afraid I can't see where this answers the question.

Comment: @tofro it covers question 1, doesn't it?